# Why isn't Apache Traffic Server updated official package manager channels?

Tags: 14.04

So I'm trying to get ATS working on a new server. Noticed the official `apt-get install trafficserver` is only version 3.2.x but if I download and build ATS from code I'm at version 5.3.0.

I'm having issues with getting it running properly from source (built and configured fine but somehow is not starting properly). I've been looking for an updated 5.3.x package but can't find any.

Is there any reason why the official package management/distribution doesn't have this up to date with the latest ATS version?

Comment: Ah, interesting. Did not know that. I know ATS has been fairly stable and being on 5.3 it's a pretty big release gap from what is out there right now. Wonder if the maintainer is busy. Wish I could find an alternative installation route.

Comment: What about this PPA? https://launchpad.net/~apache-helpdesk/+archive/ubuntu/trafficserver-ppa